# Laptop powers down for no apparent reason

Tags: 12.04, crash

Over the past day, my laptop which is running Ubuntu 12.04 has been abruptly powering down for no apparent reason. It has a full battery charge, so there are no issues there.

I can't think of any reason why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated because this is leading to a lot of unsaved work being lost.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? You get a kernel panic? It just hangs/reboots? Or is just your DE (Unity) that crashes? You should also check `/var/log/syslog` and see if you can find any clue there that could help to diagnose what's happening.

Comment: Shuts down. One moment its fine and is working the next, the laptop has shut down as if the battery was removed. I'll check syslog

Comment: This sounds like the CPU is over heating.  If you find no logs in the location above that shows a crash then this is very likely.  The CPU will stop working if it is overheating and the computer will crash.  Some CPU's will shut down the computer gracefully(like pushing the power button) some will just crash. If you see that the vents are dusty, at the very least clean them out, you might even want to take the cover off and blow out the CPU heat sink.

Comment: @TrailRider, i checked syslog and at that particular time there seems to be nothing uncanny, so i guess it must be overheating.

Comment: Let me add here that it is best to buy the canned air they sell in the electronics dept of most stores made for cleaning out electronics.  It seems kinda pricey at $4 a can(around here) but any moisture or impurities are bad for you internals and the $4 investment in cheap insurance against a new motherboard....(you may have known all this already but just in case you didn't, I posted it)

Comment: indeed, saves you the added trouble and expenditure later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your laptop's crashes could be caused by several possible reasons. I will discuss one possible reason, overheating, in this answer. Overheating is an easy problem to detect. You can continually monitor your computer's hardware temperatures using an application from the Ubuntu Software Center called Psensor.

Install Psensor. Also install lm-sensors to detect your computer's hardware sensors.

```
sudo apt-get install psensor sensors-applet lm-sensors
```

Then detect your computer's hardware sensors by opening the terminal and running the command:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Then you will get asked a lot of questions about what hardware you want the program to detect. It is generally safe and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions, unless you know what you're doing.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Psensor detect your computer's hardware sensors automatically without running `sudo sensors-detect`

Psensor is displayed on the desktop as a little thermometer icon in the notification area in the upper right-hand corner of the desktop. You can right-click the thermometer icon at any time to display the hardware temperatures. As a general guideline, a hardware temperature of 60<sup>o</sup> C is hot. A hardware temperature of 70<sup>o</sup> C and above is too hot, and could cause your system to crash.

Comment: +1 overheating was my thought as well, your answer posted as I was typing my comment so now my comment seems redundant. Oh well, +1 and great answer anyway.

Comment: @karel, from what i saw in the syslog and the absence of anything strange in it to indicate otherwise, i'm pretty sure your point of it being a case of overheating is the cause. 
thanks!

Comment: 70 C is not too hot. Modern CPUs are all designed to run up to 100 C, some even 105 C. Many laptops will shoot by 70 C as soon as the CPU spikes, and that's how they're designed. The CPU will throttle to reduce heat generation when it gets too hot. In my opinion 85 and above is uncomfortable, while 95 is cause for real concern.