# Installed fglrx and Selected fglrx-update from Software Settings - Now Black Screen on Boot

Tags: drivers, 13.10, fglrx

I have been tinkering around because I find that Ubuntu 13.10 (which I have as dual boot on my Asus laptop) get my computer a little hot and I get some crashing issues sometimes when watching videos, and more crashes when using slimboat.

Reading around a bit, I (wisely or otherwise) installed fglrx, and then I went into System Settings > Software Updates and in one of the tabs there selected "proprietary driver fglrx update". On rebooting my laptop into Ubuntu, I hear the login sound, but get a black screen.

Since I cannot get into System Settings now to change the graphics card driver back, what can I do?

My graphics card is an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 1 GB. My laptop is 86_64 bit.

**EDIT:** I looked at the page that gives advice about how to fix the problem of booting to a black screen. I installed Ubuntu a few weeks ago successfully, and have been using it just fine with the exception of some crashing with video files and browsers, as explained above. So the advice for a new install doesn't apply, and grub is working just fine so the dual boot advise doesn't apply either.

I did follow the advise about ATI Radeon drivers:

```
If your graphics card is ATI, follow these steps:

    In the GRUB menu at startup, press "e"; then
    Use the arrow keys to replace quiet splash with radeon.modeset=0.
    Then press the Ctrl+x key combination to boot.
```

This did not work either (and I also tried "nomodeset"). Although I did get the purple screen straight out of grub (which I wasn't getting), only to go black before the login screen and the login sound.

**The issue here is that I messed around with the graphics driver**, and would like to be able to get in long enough to change my settings as explained in my opening 3 paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

4. Now you're logged in to a text-only console where you can change your graphics driver from whatever you have now (fglrx-updates???) back to whatever driver you had that was working before (for example, *fglrx* if that's what driver you were using that was working before). *"Reading around a bit, I (wisely or otherwise) installed fglrx, and then I went into System Settings > Software Updates and in one of the tabs there selected `proprietary driver fglrx update`."*

If you can't get into a text only console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 you need to boot into recovery mode.

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.) With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GRUB menu. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GRUB screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

[image: GNU GRUB menu]

Press the down arrow key until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you should see this recovery menu:

[image: recovery menu]

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **network** and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see a root prompt, something like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~#
```

At this stage you should have a read-only filesystem. You have to remount it with write permissions:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Now uninstall the current graphics drivers and then reinstall the one you had before that worked.

```
apt-get remove fglrx-updates
```

5. Reboot the system by running the command: `reboot`

6. Now you have gone back to the graphics driver you had originally,  whatever Ubuntu 13.10 installed by default. Try it for a while and test if it works. Afterwards you can decide whether or not to try to install the proprietary fglrx driver.

Comment: Hi there @karel - at what point in the boot up process do I press "Ctrl + Alt + F1". It is just before I hear the login drums that things go blank. I notice now too that my screen is not "black" but actually goes "blank".

Comment: When you get to the blank screen and it stops, try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 from there. Also there are four fglrx updates drivers: fglrx-updates, fglrx-updates-dev, fglrx-updates:i386,  and fglrx-updates-dev:i386 and I don't know which one of these four drivers you now have installed (which is the one to uninstall before you go back to fglrx).

Comment: "Ctrl + Alt + F1" not working on the blank screen. I cannot remember which flgrx I downloaded (I am newbie), but it was not the one with an "update" in it. It was a 1-liner, possibly `sudo apt-get install fglrx`. The thing was that in my system settings, following the install of fglrx, there was the default option (can;t remeber what it was called, but believe it was the one Ubuntu was using on install), and then there was a "fglrx" option and also a "fglrx-update" option. The "fglrx" option was automatically selected, but I changed it to the "fglrx-update" option. Probably not a good idea!

Comment: There is no package called fglrx-update. The closest match to that in the Ubuntu Software Center is the package called _fglrx-updates_. If you can't get into the console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1, there is another, more complicated way to do it. Meanwhile ignore my answer until I have time to come back and change it.

Comment: In my BIOS (are we talking grub?) I have an option for "advanced options for ubuntu", and that takes me to a screen like the first pic your posted, where I choose the second option "recovery mode". From there I get a screen almost like the second pic. There are options for "Resume", "Clean", "dpkg", "grub" and "root", but there is no "netroot". There is "Networking", but that does not take me to a shell.

Comment: Also - I don't know what graphics driver I had originally, it was whatever Ubuntu 13.10 installed by default.

Comment: Correct error in comment #2. In Ubuntu 13.10 there are only two fglrx-updates packages: fglrx-updates and fglrx-updates-dev. Also, before/if you try to reinstall the proprietary graphics driver, search in the Dash for _Additional  Drivers_, click the Additional Drivers icon and the Additional Drivers window will pop up. This is a graphical application that has additional helpful features in it, such as recommending which driver to choose.

Comment: thanks I got my screen back! This time I went to the "additional drivers" tab, and there is the option to choose `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates` proprietary drivers. I tried both of them, but they both gave me the blank screen where I can here the login drums, but can't see a thing. I used your guidance here to revert back to the Xorg driver each time to get the screen back. Still things are a little hot with the Xorg driver, cpu hits 150% at times when watching a vid in VLC. In firefox I changed cache setting from 350mb to 10mb, which helps reduce cpu when watching vids in firefox.

Comment: "Things are a little hot with the Xorg driver" is worrisome. Take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/317150/laptop-powers-down-for-no-apparent-reason/317157#317157 for information about how to use _Psensor_ to monitor your CPU temperatures to check if your computer is ever overheating.

Comment: Yikes my `temp1`, `temp2`, `core0`, `core2` are all between 72 and 85 degrees celcius! That is with just terminal open and Psensor open! Having opened a movie in VLC, the ranges have changed between 82 - 91 celcius, with 67% cpu usage. However, the fan in my laptop doesn't do its job, so I always have an exeternal fan plugged in.

Comment: That could also explain why fglrx isn't working. Maybe there's a lot of dust in the aluminum cooling block inside your laptop case. It wouldn't cost much to have a computer technician open the laptop and clean out the dust.

Comment: I found a manual, and a youtube vid for how to clean the fan in my laptop, never done it before. So cleaned the fan and the vent and now core temperatures are in the 50 - 60 degree celcius range, even with firefox playing youtube vids, and VLC on, and other programs open at the same time. Cpu hardly gets above 50% So that was definitely the problem! Looks like I don't need to try fglrx now, since there is not a problem, but will give it a shot later just to see if the blank screen problem goes away

Comment: Also, I have lost sound in VLC player during the attempts to get fglrx running. Uninstalled and reinstalled VLC, but still no sound.

Comment: There's a mute sound on/off button in the lower right-hand corner of VLC that looks like a little line drawing of a speaker. Click on it and the volume color changes back and forth from green/orange to gray.

Comment: Oops, that was it (feeling silly).

Comment: Since I uninstalled and reinstalled VLC, and then run autoremove, how come VLC kept my mute setting? I noticed the same thing with Slimboat, I uninstalled and reinstalled, and when opening Slimboat asked if I wanted to restore my tabs from last session. Is there a way to flush these settings after removing a program?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there's a way to do it because I even have to do something similar in order to backup my system settings before doing a clean install, but whatever it is it would be much harder to do than simply changing the settings back to the way they were before from inside the application windows. These settings are stored inside hidden configuration files and it's VERY complicated and hard to understand in there.